# I mistakely pasted my own blockchain recieving address in the send slot

Tags: blockchain

I mistakely pasted my own blocchain receiving address in my Send slot to send BTC to friend.  I usually recieve a Either send or recieve responds in my record, but this time I got a TRANSFERRED respond.  Even it was my own receiving address and took 100 confirmation blockhain never returned those BTC back to my own wallet.  You think that even if I used my own receiving address will i get back those BTC?
Thanks,
Albert

Comment: double post: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53091/i-mistakely-pasted-my-own-blockchain-recieving-address

Answer (score 0):

You wont get the transaction fee back.

As you did make a new transaction which requires a miner fee.