# Accidentally sent to my own receiving address, will I get back my bitcoins?

Tags: blockchain.info, lost-bitcoins

I mistakenly pasted my own Blockchain.info receiving address into the recipient field when I was trying to send BTC to a friend. I usually receive either a "send" or "receive" notification in my records, but this time I got a "transferred" notification. Even though it was my own receiving address it took 100 confirmations and blockchain.info never returned my BTC back to my own wallet. I'm not asking for my fees to be returned but about the whole bitcoin I sent. Do you think that I will get back my BTC even if I used my own receiving address?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin doesn't know that the recipient address is also yours. Therefore, while you sent the money to yourself, it looks like any other Bitcoin transaction to any other network participant.

To your wallet provider (blockchain.info) it is obvious that you control both addresses, so they call it a "transfer" instead of a "send".

As you've sent it to your own receiving address, you should be able to see it counted towards your balance. If it hasn't been, get in touch with blockchain.info and request that they help you rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

You already own these bitcoins while you ve sent them to your own address. Check the transaction you have made in blockchain.info explorer. You can spend these btc again there is no problem with that.

Comment: Hi Badr, thanks for yor commends and info.  I checked the transations in the blockchain info explorer and I see there the total that went out if ever went out and the total the came in if ever out. my Quiestion is How can I use it if this btc is not showing in my Sent and Receive slot it shows transferred. where i get them to use it again? is ther a way to get it and use?  Thanks again Albert